# TYPO3 - How to prevent FTP 150 alert

Tags: ftp, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I always get this alert before downloading a file or loading my page where I provide a file for download which is stored on a FTP server. It must be related to the extension **FAL_FTP_Driver** because the alert does only appear since I upgraded from 1.2 to 1.3. But I also get it after changing to 1.2 again which is strange.

I already checked the permissions of the folder and files on the ftp server.
It is set to `drwxr-xr-x` for folders and `-rw-r--r--` for files. They all have `root root` as user and group.

[image]

Does someone know how to prevent it? 
The alert shows on firefox (with ubuntu and mac) but does not appear on chrome (mac)

Comment: Does the download URL begin with `ftp://`?

Comment: yes it starts with ftp, i will post an example url tomorrow

Comment: In that case, the problem should be somewhere on the browser side, or on the FTP servers side - TYPO3 shouldn't have much to do with it.

Comment: It does only appear since I have updatet the TYPO3 Extension FAL_FTP_Driver, so TYPO3 has something to do with it.